# SocketTimeoutException when parsing JSON from website

Tags: java, html, json, jsoup

I need help with parsing HTML with Jsoup from:
https://www.sierra.com/clearance~1/women~d~5324/specdataor~gender!women/colorfamily~red/priceor~%2410-%2414dotdot99/3/.

When I am trying to parse any HTML I get

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out.

With other URLs, this code is working fine.

How can I solve this problem?

```
private void Parsedata(){
  try {
        String URL = "https://www.sierra.com/clearance~1/women~d~5324/specdataor~gender!women/colorfamily~red/priceor~%2410-%2414dotdot99/3/";
            System.out.println(getPage(URL));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static Document getPage(String URL) throws IOException {
  Document page = Jsoup.connect(URL).timeout(0).execute().parse();
  return page;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you are trying to connect to is requiring a valid user agent. You can set it by using `Connection.userAgent()`. You can use the current Chrome version for example:

```
private static Document getPage(String URL) throws IOException {
    return Jsoup.connect(URL)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36")
            .timeout(10_000).execute().parse();
}
```